# What is Post Cache substitution?

Tags: asp.net

What is Post Cache substitution and how it is implemented in the asp.net page?

Answer (score 1):

This is way to replace part of cached page before give back it to user. So IIS will take hole page from output cache and re-render a bit part of it.

Answer (score 0):

To allow you to cache a page but substitute some content dynamically, you can use ASP.NET post-cache substitution. With post-cache substitution, the entire page is output cached with specific parts marked as exempt from caching. In the example of the ad banners, the AdRotator control allows you to take advantage of post-cache substitution so that ads dynamically created for each user and for each page refresh.
[Dynamically Updating Portions of a Cached Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227429.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Post-cache substitution is the feature of ASP.NET:

- it enables to substitute dynamic content in a page that has been cached in memory on *server*-side
- provided by [Response.WriteSubstitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.writesubstitution?view=netframework-4.8)-method

*Controllers\About.cs*

```cs
public class AboutController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(Duration=120)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // ..

    public static string RenderDynamicContent(HttpContext context)
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

*Views\About\Index.aspx*

```html
<!-- ... -->
Substituted content:
<% Response.WriteSubstitution(AboutController.RenderDynamicContent); %>

Fixed content (cached): 
<%= DateTime.Now %>
<!-- ... -->
```

see for details [MS docs: Adding Dynamic Content to a Cached Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/adding-dynamic-content-to-a-cached-page-cs)